# Can I make a link 1. navigate away from page and 2. execute Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have a piece of javascript code that I want to execute on the page a user navigates to.
So I have

```
<a href="www.google.com">
```

and once he clicks it I want to execute

```
javascript:Alert("you're on google")
```

Is there anyway to do this?

I thought of setting up a PHP page somewhere that accepts a URL as a parameter and then wraps the js in it, but that would affect my webserver traffic and probably not work for session based websites...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, no. Or, at least, you are not supposed to be able to do that. Running your javascript on someone else's web site is a gigantic security hole.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that and I can also see why. I'm making something similar to http://kathack.com/, and I Was wondering if I can make it so that when a link is clicked, it will also have the effect.

Comment: Well, you can certainly do what they did...make it a bookmarklet. Then your script is running locally on their machine independent of your site.

Comment: yeah, I've gotten that far, but I was just wondering is there was a way to make it so that if you would then click a link, the same effect would be present. Here's what I have so far: http://joon.be/ipadexperience/ , logically the effect disappears when a link is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can for sure **execute a script** **then** **navigate away**.
But if you want to execute your script on the next page, **in short**, it is not possible (or all browsers try their best to make it not possible). This is related to cross-page security.

```
<a onclick="yourscript()" href="http://www.google.com">go to google</a>
```

If you are thinking about cross-domain scripting, you can google for

**cross domain scripting**

or **cross domain ajax etc**